# This pattern seems wrong in angular. Multiple calls to an api is generating multiple subscriptions

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2+ app I have the following:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      this.rowid = params.get('rowid')
      
      this.apiService.getrow(this.rowid).subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;
        //Validations
        if (this.data == null) return;
        if (!("oid" in data)) return;
        let oid:string =data["oid"]
      })
    })
  }
}
```

This seems wrong because every time the params change we create a new api service call that create a new subscription.
I rather not use activatedRoute snapshot.
Is there a better pattern for this.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to get value from `this.activatedRoute.paramMap` only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with a pipe:

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.apiService.getrow(this.rowid).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(...)
```

and it will take a value from sub and unsubscribe.

If you don't want to watch for url params changes, you can consider using BehaviorSubjects. Thus, you can create a service that gets and sets the `rowid` value as a BehaviorSubject, and then subscribe to it instead of the router. Inside that subscription, you can subscribe to api service (and you can also use take1 there).

Comment: Thanks.  I must have been looking at old documentation.  I was trying to do a take(1) but not within a pipe.  Your solution seems to work well.